# C# EF6 cascade delete not working

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, delete-row

Using C# Entity framework 6 and Database first approach, for some reason cascade delete is just working if i delete a row executing a query directly in Management Studio, but it is not working if the row is deleted with code.

I have two tables: Source and Media. One Media can have many sources (.mp4, .avi, etc).
In my database i want cascade delete for the Source table, so when a Media is deleted all the Sources with its reference are deleted too.

Using SQL Managemend Studio i have defined foreign key relationship "FK_Source_Media" with Cascade Delete.
In Visual Studio i have the following picture of the relationship once updated from the database:

[image: FK_Media_Source onDelete Cascade]

I think tha everything is ok... But, as i said at the begining of the post, the cascade delete on Source works only executing a query like

```
  delete from Media where Id=183
```

But executing the following piece of code to delete a row programatically with EF don't:

```
public void DeleteVMDBEntity(T TObject)
    {            
        specificContext.Attach(TObject);            
        var entry = context.Entry(TObject);
        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
        specificContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

After executing that code the Media row is deleted properly, but the Sources with a MediaId reference just set the MediaId to null and are not deleted as expected.

Why is it happening?

Comment: check how to set property on cascade in EF6

Comment: property is already set onCascade, as shown in the picture

Comment: Do you really need `Source` w/o `Media`? In other words, currently you made the relationship optional (0..1). EF treats CascadeDelete option differently for such type of relationship - it sets all source related media records `MediaId` to `null` before deleting the media record.

Comment: Ok, i've changed the relationship to 1..* and the problem now is an Exception telling me that it's not possible to set MediaId to null. I'll update the post with the new behaviour and try to put the exact Exception.